# XPath greater than operator?

Tags: xpath, eventlog-source

I'm trying to select all event log entries beyond a certain date.  So far I think I got equals, but I don't know how to change this to greater than the specified date...  so close yet so far!

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime='2013-01-01T12:21:25.0000000']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: Presumably this is an XPath 1.0 question, because in 2.0 it would be trivial. You really need to say.

Comment: Sorry not an XPath expert. Query would run against the eventlog of a Windows Server 2008 R2. Does that help?

Comment: There are many different XPath processors that run on Windows, some support XPath 2.0 and some don't. XPath 2.0 allows order comparisons on strings; XPath 1.0 does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way to create a XPath query for EventLog.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709635.aspx) on how to create a custom view.  After you create the custom view, with whatever filter you want, simply click on the XML, and voila, it shows you the XPath query that it constructed itself!

The next challenge was the formating of the date.  I used this: "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:fffZ"

I also think you cannot create a filter that says, shows me everything after this date.  So I simply recreated a range between the date I wanted and the current date.

For completeness, here is the filter that I created (who dreams up specs for this?)

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Application">
<Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1 or Level 2 or Level=3) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2013-01-01T12:00:00:000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='2013-02-13T05:30:34:948Z']]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: For future reference: if one would like to use @codeputer query as an "inline" query (not sure what's the correct term), i.e., to only use the text under the `Select` tag, then `gt;=` and `lt;=` should be replaced with `>=` and `<=` respectively. I got an exception otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
*[System[TimeCreated[
    number(translate(substring-before(@SystemTime, 'T'), '-', '')) > 20130101]]]
```

If you need to consider the entire string, then strip everything unnecessary to the comparison:

```
*[System[TimeCreated[
    number(translate(@SystemTime, '-T:.', '')) > 201301011221250000000]]]
```

Comment: I'm trying this by create a view in the event log and pasting in the XML.  It tells me there is an error, but nothing else.  I've tried both.  I notice however that > gets changed to &gt; which can't be right.   How do I prevent that?

Comment: OP was trying to query event logs, [which only supports a subset of XPath 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa385231(v=vs.85)#selection-limitations). It seems that `number`, `translate`, `substring-before` are not supported.